# How to configure SVN to not allow any code changes to few JIRA's until some specific date?

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook

I'm working in Product based company and usually we do customization to client.

We are working in JIRA system to commit changes to tortoise SVN repo.

Is it possible to lock the SVN repo for committing changes to few JIRA's till specific date?

Thanks in advance,
Prasad

Comment: Most likely what you need is a **pre-commit hook**

Comment: Please clarify your requirements. How do you propose to map a commit to a specific (set of) Jira ticket(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Just some clarifications, which will help you when researching answers for your question.

- "Tortoise SVN" is a client (to SVN server). There is no such thing as "Tortoise SVN repo".
- SVN server is not aware of JIRA in any normal sense.
- A pre-commit hook (read below) is executed on SVN server, and has nothing to do with client side or Tortoise SVN.

What you can use is a **pre-commit hook**. This hook is a script that will be executed on your SVN server every time there is a commit. When it executes, it can read the SVN commit message, and if that message contains a mention of a certain JIRA number that you want to "block", the script should fail, blocking the commit in the process.

There are a few issues with this:

- Firstly, it is easy to circumvent: if someone doesn't mention the JIRA number in the commit message, or mentions wrong JIRA number, the script will not help you.
- Secondly, if you plan to do it on large scale, maintaining a list of "blocked" JIRA through a script will be a nightmare. There is no GUI for this.

The script will need to be written in `.batch` or `.bash`, depending on the OS of the SVN server. You can find online lots of sample pre-commit scripts, but for your specific needs, you will need to modify it yourself.

Bottom line is: neither SVN nor JIRA are going to **ensure** that code relating to specific areas is not modified. A pre-commit hook can help in accidental mistakes, but it won't stop someone doing it deliberately.

What you really need is a **Peer Code Review** tool, something like [**Crucible**](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CRUCIBLE027/Getting+Started+with+Crucible)